# Why am I not able to assign a nested class to its parents?

Tags: java

Give the following code

```
interface C {
  void g();
}

class A {
  int x = 1;

  C f() {
    int y = 1;

    class B extends A implements C {
      public void g() {
        A.this.x = y; // accessing x and y is OK.
      }
    }
    B b = new B();
    return b;
  }
}
```

I tried to run the following line of commands:

```
A a = new A().f();
```

However, it throws an incompatible type error that C cannot be converted to A.

I do not understand why this is throwing an error as the text I was reading was executing the following commands:

```
A a = new A();
C b = a.f();
b.g();
```

And they mentioned that:

> Calling the commands above will give us a reference to an object of type B now

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Edit: I ran the following codes on jshell.

Edit 2: Mistakes.

Comment: `C.this.y` doesn't compile in Java. A simple `y` will.

Comment: `new A.f()` makes no sense. The 3 lines that does work can be merged to `C b = new A().f(); b.g();`, or even `new A().f().g();`

Comment: I edited my code, wouldn't `A a = new A().f()`  return a type B? I am confuse because the text I was reading mentioned that the 3 lines that works returns a reference to a type B. So I thought that by doing `A a = new A().f()`, it will work fine since B extends A? Is my way of thinking wrong?

Comment: `C a = new A().f();` because `f()` returns `C`. Simple as that. Also, this is why meaningless class / interface names are a bad idea. Why is your base interface named `C`?

Comment: Example given from the text I was given by my university and I am just building upon it. Here where I got the code from: https://nus-cs2030s.github.io/2021-s2/26-nested-classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider compile time type information. Even though you can tell that `B` is an `A` and the `C` reference return from `f()` is an instance of `B` **the compiler only knows that objects returned from `f()` implement `C`**. It would be wrong to infer any concrete type. After all, you may return any concrete type from `f()` so long as it implements `C`.  You could check manually by calling `instanceof` and or cast the instance `A a = (A) new A().f();` but this is generally not a great idea. It will make your code break if you want to add additional `C` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The function `f()` of `A` returns an Object of class `C`. You cannot assign `C` to `A`. `A` would need to implement `C` for that.

Comment: Even if `A` implemented `C`, it would still have to be cast explicitly for the code to compile.